# How do you generate mean from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

How do you generate mean from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1
with a sample size of 10? using excel?

Do you have to first generate random numbers from 0 to 1?

Comment: I don't remember much from the course I took on it, but if I understand what you're asking, maybe something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling would work?

Answer (score 1):

To have a "sample size of 10" we need to take 10 samples from the distribution.  In Excel, this is achieved by:

```
=RAND()
```

So type this into one cell, then click and drag this to fill 10 cells, say cells A1 to A10.  Then to compute the sample mean:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A10)
```

The actual mean is $0.5$, so the sample mean should be somewhat close to this.

This is what it looks like on my computer:

[image: Example on my computer]

(This is actually [LibreOffice Calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/calc/), but I believe the syntax is the same.)